# Making a linked list without built in functions

Tags: python, list, class, linked-list, nodes

I have a project to make a linked list in python.

My program needs to add to the list, remove from it and get elements. Sounds easy right? Wrong! We aren't allowed to use normal lists or built-in functions (other than the basic `print`, `str`...)

I have one problem with my code, I have to initialise a blank list then add the elements, 1 by 1. Everything else works fine.

**My questions:**

> Is this how a normal python list works?
>
> Is it possible to add items to a linked list with a loop? (without another list)

**Here's the code:**

```
class Node: # the node class
    def __init__(self, cargo = None, next = None): # __init__ stands for initialize
        self.cargo = cargo # e.g. steve
        self.next = next # represents the next node or None if its the last

    def __str__(self): # __str__ is called when the node is printed or converted to a string
        return str(self.cargo) # return a string

class List: # the main list class
    def __init__(self): # default is to initialize an empty list
        self.first_node = None      
        self.last_node = None
        self.length = 0

    def get(self, position, length): # function for efficiency
        if position == "end":
            position = length - 1 # last
        if position > length - 1: # can't go beyond last
            raise ValueError("List index out of range")

        prv_node = self.first_node
        node = self.first_node # start at the first
        num = 0
        while num < position: # go up to position
            prv_node = node # remember the previous node
            node = node.next # next node!
            num = num + 1

        return prv_node, node, position

    def add_node(self, cargo, position = "end"): # adds a node
        prv_node, node, position = self.get(position, self.length + 1) # +1 because the length is being increased

        print("adding node at "+str(position)+": "+str(cargo))            
        if position == 0: # first
            self.first_node = Node(cargo, next = self.first_node) # the first node is the new node
            if self.length == 0: # first node to be added
                self.last_node = self.first_node # there is only one node
        elif position == self.length: # last
            self.last_node.next = Node(cargo, next = None) # last_node.next was None, it is now a new node
            self.last_node = self.last_node.next # last node is now the new last node
        else: # normal
            prv_node.next = Node(cargo, next = node) # stick it in between
        self.length = self.length + 1 # length is now + 1

    def get_node(self, position): # gets a node
        ...

    def remove_node(self, position): # removes a node 
        ...

    def __str__(self): # when the list is printed
        node = self.first_node # start from the first
        string = ""
        while node != self.last_node: # go to the end
            string = string + str(node) + ", "  # print each node
            node = node.next
        string = string + str(self.last_node) # last node hasn't been added yet
        return string
            
# initialize    
mylist = List()
mylist.add_node("steve")
mylist.add_node("james")
mylist.add_node("tom")
mylist.add_node("david")
mylist.add_node("hoe-yin")
mylist.add_node("daniel")
print(mylist)
```

[EDIT] second question re-phrased

Comment: What do u mean by your second question?

Comment: "*Is this how a normal python list works*" - might be, might not.  The language does not specify *how* lists are implemented, only the features required.  The C implementation uses a C array of pointers to Python objects but the objects themselves do not contain links, so in that case, no.

Comment: What do you mean by asking "Is it possible to initialize a linked list with a loop?" ? You want to know if is there a way to add items to the list in loop?

Comment: Nf4r, yes. I want to add items to the list with a loop but without using a list in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how Python lists are implemented in CPython: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/

If you have your values in some other iterable, then yes:

```
for item in list_of_items:
    mylist.add_node(item)
```

Comment: This would work, but I can't use the variable list_of_items because it's a built-in python list

Comment: @TomFuller I suppose you could do it with `input`, but that's probably not allowed either.  The thing about loops is you have to have something to loop over or extract values from

Comment: I agree, all the websites I've looked at say the same thing

Comment: If you're only forbidden from using lists, you could get a little cheeky and use a tuple: `for item in ('steve', 'james', 'tom'):`

Comment: Yeah, i'll probably do something like that